# why does @beforeGroups execute twice, and @afterGroups execute once in this scenario?

Tags: java, testng

I have tests spread out across multiple classes that a part of a group, and there is a class that has the @beforeGroups method and @afterGroups method for that group. This has been working as expected:

```
@Test(groups = { "group1"})
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"group1"}, alwaysRun = false)
@AfterGroups(groups = {"group1"}, alwaysRun = false)
```

... the methods with the @beforeGroups and @afterGroups decorator would only execute once, as expected.

The runtime of the suite was starting to grow, so I wanted to identify a subset of the tests into a 'sanity' suite, and did so like this:

```
@Test(groups = { "group1", "sanity"})
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"group1"}, alwaysRun = false)
@AfterGroups(groups = {"group1"}, alwaysRun = false)
```

... and when I changed the suite XML file to reflect this by adding:

```
<groups>
  <run>
    <include name="sanity" />
  </run>
</groups>
```

... I noticed that the beforeGroups code didn't run. So I changed the @beforeGroups and @afterGroups to reflect that sanity group as such:

```
@BeforeGroups(groups = {"group1", "sanity"}, alwaysRun = false)
@AfterGroups(groups = {"group1", "sanity"}, alwaysRun = false)
```

Now here's where it gets weird. I was hoping that the @beforeGroups and @afterGroups would only run once. But not only did I have a problem with it running twice -- only @beforeGroups ran twice, not @afterGroups!

So my questions are:

1) Is it a bug that in my example above, @beforeGroups ran twice where @afterGroups ran once? I'm not ever sure what the correct behavior is, but it seems like it would be the same for both..

2) What is the proper way to proceed? I'm simply looking to define a suite file that identifies a subset of tests as sanity tests, but I want the @beforeGroup and @afterGroup for those tests to still run. (But not run twice).

Comment: It looks like a bug. Could you open an issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues ?

Comment: I tried reproducing this using TestNG 6.11 and I can't seem to reproduce this issue. Can you please try this once again using TestNG 6.11 (latest released version of TestNG) ?